# javascript find closest element within viewport and scroll to it

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: View port with options scrolled half way between two of the options]

I have a view-port div which is 48px high and 400px wide. Inside that view-port, I have another div which contains a list of divs. Each of the divs in the list are 48px high and 400px wide. There is obviously an overflow here and the goal is to have it so when the user stops scrolling it will find the closest element to the view-port. My code is below:

javascript, html, and css:

```js
var i;
window.onload = function(){
    var timer = null;
    var optionsScrollTop = 0;
    var selectLists = document.getElementsByClassName('selectList');
    for(i = 0; i != selectLists.length; i++)
    {
        var currentElement = i;
        document.getElementsByClassName('selectList')[currentElement].onmouseover = function()
        {
            //alert(currentElement+' mousover');
            document.getElementById('contentContainer').style.overflow = 'hidden';
        };
        
        document.getElementsByClassName('selectList')[currentElement].onmouseout = function()
        {
            //alert(currentElement+' mouseout');
            document.getElementById('contentContainer').style.overflow = 'auto';
        };
        
        var options = document.getElementsByClassName('selectList')[currentElement].getElementsByClassName('selectListOptions')[0].getElementsByClassName('option');
        for(var j = 0; j != options.length; j++)
        {
            var oldTitle = '';
            
            options[j].onmouseover = function()
            {
                this.parentElement.parentElement.title = this.title;
                oldTitle = this.title;
                this.title = '';
            };
            
            options[j].onmouseout = function()
            {
                this.title = oldTitle;  
            };
        }
        
        document.getElementsByClassName('selectList')[currentElement].onscroll = function()
        {
            if(timer !== null) {
                clearTimeout(timer);
            }
            timer = setTimeout(function(){
                var allOptionOffsets = [];
                var selectViewPortOffset = document.getElementsByClassName('selectList')[currentElement].offsetTop;
                var options = document.getElementsByClassName('selectList')[currentElement].getElementsByClassName('selectListOptions')[0].getElementsByClassName('option');
                for(var i = 0; i != options.length; i++)
                {  
                    allOptionOffsets.push(options[i].offsetTop);
                    //selectViewPortOffset
                }
                
                for(var i = 0; i != allOptionOffsets.length; i++)
                {
                    alert(allOptionOffsets[i]+' element '+i);
                    alert('viewport offset: '+selectViewPortOffset);
                    if(allOptionOffsets[i] ==  selectViewPortOffset-24 || allOptionOffsets[i] ==  selectViewPortOffset+24)
                    {
                        alert(i+' is closest');
                    }
                       //selectViewPortOffset
                    /*if(allOptionOffsets[i]-selectViewPortOffset > 0)
                    {
                        if(allOptionOffsets[i]-selectViewPortOffset < 48)
                        {
                            document.getElementsByClassName('selectList')[currentElement].scrollTop = allOptionOffsets[i]-selectViewPortOffset;
                        }
                    }*/
                    
                    //alert(allOptionOffsets[i]);
                }
            }, 1000);
        };
    }
};

/*
 var viewPortOffset = document.getElementsByClassName('selectList')[currentElement].offsetTop;
                var optionsOffset = [];
                var options = document.getElementsByClassName('selectList')[currentElement].getElementsByClassName('selectListOptions')[0].getElementsByClassName('option');
                for(var i = 0; i != options.length; i++)
                {
                    var optionOffset = document.getElementsByClassName('selectList')[currentElement].getElementsByClassName('selectListOptions')[0].getElementsByClassName('option')[i].offsetTop;
                    optionsOffset.push(optionOffset);
                }
                
                for(var i = 0; i < optionsOffset.length; i++)
                {
                    alert(optionsOffset[i]);   
                }
*/
```

```css
.selectList
{
    width:400px;
    height:48px;
    border:2px solid #000;
    border-radius:5px;
    overflow:auto;
}

.selectListOptions
{
    text-align:center;
}

.selectListOptions .option
{
    font-size:30px;
    height:48px;
    text-align:center;
    border-top:1px solid #000;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    -o-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.selectListOptions .label
{
    font-size:30px;
    height:48px;
    text-align:center;
    border-top:1px solid #000;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="simulatorOfOtherContentThisNormalyWouldn'tBeHere" style="padding:10%">



<div class="selectList" id="incomingMessageSound">
                        <div class="selectListOptions">
                            <div class="label option" title='optionDefault'>Incoming Message Sound</div>
                            <div class="option" title='option2'>Sound 1</div>
                            <div class="option" title='option3'>Sound 2</div>
                            <div class="option" title='option4'>Sound 3</div>
                            <div class="option" title='option5'>Sound 4</div>
                            <div class="option" title='option6'>Sound 5</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>




</div>
```

Comment: When the user stops scrolling, javscript would loop through the select options (the super child divs) in the list and get the offset of each one. Then javascript would compare it with the offset of the view-port div. As I read more about offsetTop, I found that it just returns the offset from the parent element. This posed a problem because it was returning the offset of In this case selectListOptions div. I need to find the offset of the elements relative to the super parent selectList div.

Comment: Can you post a snippet with the code?

Comment: I added the code snippet. You can see it.

Comment: @www139 - since height is 48px, scrolling is maybe not the most user friendly event, actually, scroller is so small that click seems like much better solution? (in that case you can simplify your js easy, set overflow:hidden, add two buttons 'up' and 'down' and slide elements easily)?

Comment: I was trying to create a new type of select list where the user scrolls to select an option. My first idea was where the user would scroll and then script would find which direction the user was scrolling and move down to the next or previous option accordingly. The one I have in this question is where the user scrolls and then the script is supposed to find the closest element relative to the view-port. I tried coding the first version and I couldn't figure it out which is why I'm now creating prototype 2. A button would work but it wouldn't provide the same effect.

Comment: You could also implement the selection on click on the element, this way you won't need the scrolling logic and also will avoid problems with the user scrolling too much or too little.

Comment: ok, I will try that. It doesn't seem like this idea is going to work.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it if I understood correctly (I used jQuery to save some lines):

```
function goToClosest(){

    clearTimeout(window.lastTimeout);
    window.lastTimeout = setTimeout(function(){

        var BaseOffset      = $('.selectList').offset().top + 2, // I add 2 because of border top
            ViewrportHeight = $('.selectList').height(),
            ScrollTop       = $('.selectList').scrollTop(),
            distSum         = 0,
            closest,closestDist,closestScrollTop;

        $('.selectListOptions > div').each(function(i,e){

            var e = $(e);
            var distance = Math.abs(e.offset().top - BaseOffset);
            if(!closest || closestDist > distance){
                 closest          = e;
                 closestDist      = distance;
                 closestScrollTop = distSum;
            }

            distSum += e.height() + 2; // Again +2 for border

        });

        $('.selectList').animate({scrollTop:closestScrollTop+'px'},300,'swing');

    },1000);

}

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.selectList').scroll(goToClosest);

});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8d7Ln5mc/